# Find the volume of the set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by the equation $x^2 + y^2 \leq z \leq 1 + x + y$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $D=\left\{\left(x,y,z\right) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 \leq z \leq 1 + x + y \right\}$. I tried to integrate with cartesian coordinates, so that

$$\iiint_Ddxdydz = \int_{x=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}^{{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}} \int_{z=x^2}^{1+x} \left( \int_{y=z-(1+x)}^{\sqrt{z-x^2}}dy\right)dxdz$$

but the calculation seems to be quite laborious. Is there a way to solve it easily, maybe with another coordinate system?

**Edit**: After your suggestions I finally solved the problem. If someone is interested in the calculation itself I'll report the main steps below:

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^{\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}\left(\int_{z=r^2+r(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)+\frac{1}{2}}^{r(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)+2}dz\right)rdrd\theta = \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^{\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}} \left( \frac{3}{2}r-r^3\right)drd\theta = \pi\int_{0}^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(\frac{3}{2}-t\right)dt = \frac{\pi}{2} \left[3t-t^2\right]_{0}^{\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{9\pi}{8}$$

Comment: It's interesting you chose to do $y$ first, but this isn't right. If you did $y$ first the result should be two integrals. The way the bounds are written suggests doing $z$ first.

Comment: $\frac{9 \pi}{8}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $$x=r\cos(\theta)+\frac{1}{2}$$ $$y=r\sin(\theta)+\frac{1}{2}$$ $$z=z$$ The volume of your solid is the triple integral $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{3/2}} \int_{r^2+r\big(\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)\big)+\frac{1}{2}}^{r\big(\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)\big)+2}rdzdrd\theta$$

Comment: (+1) You might want to add that that choice of coordinates becomes natural after one notices that$$x^2+y^2\leqslant1+x+y\iff\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\left(y-\frac12\right)^2\leqslant\frac32.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Use this modified cylindrical coordinate system:

$$\begin{cases}x = r\cos\left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\ y = r\sin\left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\ z = z \\\end{cases}$$

What does the change do? Does it alter the Jacobian (which measures how much the volume is distorted between coordinate systems) ?

Comment: Since $r\sin^2\left(\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}\right) + r\cos^2\left(\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}\right) = r$ the Jacobian is not altered.